# how to stop .htaccess catching the forward slash

Tags: php

i am creating site where users can search posts and sort them using various parameters.

my original url looks like this.

```
www.mydomain.com/posts.php?mode=search&category=all&q=this is search query&verified=true
```

so i have created rewrite rules in htaccess file like this.

```
RewriteRule ^search/all/(.*)/verified/$ posts.php?mode=search&category=all&q=$1&verified=true [L]
```

but when i check the $_GET array by doing

```
print_r($_GET);
```

its sending the evrything after the regex to parameter "q".

```
Array
(
    [mode] => search
    [category] => all
    [q] => this is search query/verified
)
```

how can i make it work , by not sending evrything after the regex in the rewrite rule to the "q" parameter and to that specific parameter like.

i want my output to be like

```
Array
(
    [mode] => search
    [category] => all
    [q] => this is search query
    [verified] => true
)
```

Comment: Is that your real RewriteRule? It's unlikely that `.*` would consume the `/verified/` afterwards when that isn't optionalized.

Answer (score 2):

**Search String => `B` flag**

Because your search string is getting encoded and decoded, we need to use the `B` flag.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^search/all/([^/]+)/verified/?$ posts.php?mode=search&category=all&q=$1&verified=true [L,B]
```

I also fixed your capture group: `[^/]+` matches one or more chars that are not a `/`

**Reference**

[B (escape backreferences)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is it possible to catch verified by using something like ^verified, coz if someone puts the / in the query , everything will break.

Comment: That's a valid concern. Set `AllowEncodedSlashes On`, see [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes)

Comment: Terrific, let me know how it goes.

Comment: +1 this should work as `[^/]+` is the best approach. Just make trailing slash optional i.e. `^search/all/([^/]+)/verified/?$`